# Auto Starting a python script on boot (RPi)

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I have a python script on my RPi that needs to run on boot

I added it to rc.local, and it used to work fine

A few days ago, I added a functionality to the program, and it now uses open() to read a txt file

Now every time I restart the Pi, python gives me and error:

```
File "home/pi/client.py", line 13, in <module>
    stats=open('stats.txt')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'stats.txt'
```

When I manually launch the script with:

```
sudo python client.py
```

it works fine with no problems.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rc.local` probably does not start your script in the correct directory. So you should either:

- use something like `cd my/dir && python /path/to/home/pi/client.py`
- call `os.chdir("/path/to/some_dir")` in your script
- use an absolute path when opening the file: `stats = open('/path/to/stats.txt')`

Comment: worked! thanks bud! (pressing enter posted the comment before this one :( )